# AJAX json unexpected token '

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, syntax-error

I have this code:

```
    $.ajax({
            dataType: 'text',
            url: '/_/js/answers.json',
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                alert(data.code);
                var result = JSON.parse(data);
                var hey = JSON.parse('{"code": 123}'); 
                alert(hey.code);
                alert(result.code);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("code not found");
            }
        });
```

In the first alert, `alert(data)` it shows me '{"code": 123}', in the second alert `alert(data.code)`, it tells me `undefined`, in the third alert `alert(hey.code)`, it shows me `123`, and that's what I want, but in the fourth alert, the console tells me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '`.
 
When I change the `JSON.parse` to `$.parseJSON`, it does exactly the same things.
I don't know what's wrong, the json is fine (exactly the same as the json in var hey). 
I passed the json to the server like this: 
**javascript:**

```
var json = {code: code};
        json = JSON.stringify(json);
        json = {data: json};

        $.ajax({
            url: "/_/js/write-json.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: json
        });
```

**php:**

```
    <?php
    $myFile = "answers.json";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh,var_export($_POST['data'], true));
    fclose($fh);
    ?>
```

Thanks, bhc11.

Comment: It might be that your JSON is invalid, to be sure check it [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: I have checked it, it is exactly the same as the json in var hey.

Comment: Please post the json.

Comment: Does the JSON contain singlequote characters at the beginning and end, like you showed? That isn't valid.

Comment: you say that your alert data states `'{"code": 123}'`. This includes single quotes which are not meant to be there. That is your problem.

Comment: @Barmar - ofc its valid. Its a string which is parsed!

Comment: Single quotes are part of Javascript literal syntax, they aren't part of the JSON itself.

Comment: @Barmar right, but the sample being used in the question is correctly using quotes.

Comment: alerting `result.code` shouldn't give you that syntax error. the error is coming from something else.

Comment: You can use JSON.stringify(data) or eval(data) before using it.

Comment: @LeeTaylor, that was it, I changed it to `data = $.parseJSON(data.substr(1, (data.length-2)))`, and it worked. Thanks

Comment: I think you should fix the server-side code to return valid JSON instead of taking a substring of the result when yur parse it. Just out of interest, any reason why your are not using `dataType: 'json'` and just getting an object as the `data` param?

Comment: bhc11 - Please do as @Adam has suggested. Better to have correct data to start with than trying to fix it later.

Comment: I did, but it gave me the error function. I edited the question to show how I inserted the json. Maybe that isn't the right way.

Answer (score 5):

The `'` characters around your JSON make it a JavaScript string and don't form part of the data.

It looks like you have those characters in the JSON that you are requesting over HTTP so there they *do* form part of the data.

This is not valid JSON. Remove the quotes.

You should have:

```
{"code": 123}
```

Not

```
'{"code": 123}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing dataType to JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url: '/_/js/answers.json',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        alert(data.code);
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        var hey = JSON.parse('{"code": 123}'); 
        alert(hey.code);
        alert(result.code);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("code not found");
    }
});
```

Comment: If you change the dataType to JSON then jQuery parses it for you.  So no need to `var result = JSON.parse(data);`since `data` is already an object.  However, it appears from the other comments that the returned JSONw as invalid.  THis method requires valid JSON from the server (and a valid JSON content type)

Comment: Yeah, but when I change it to json, it gives me the error function. I probably didn't pass the json in the right way to the server.

Comment: you must set header content type as 'text/json'